# Javascript FadeIn Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help with my code, This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<body onLoad="loader();">
<div class="loader"><img src="images/loader.gif></div> 
<div class="main"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
   display:none;
}
```

So, the loading Gif Is shown, and then when the page fully loads, it should do this:

```
function loader() {
 setTimeout(function () {
    $("#main").fadeIn("fast");
    $("#loader").fadeOut("fast");
}, 1000);
```

};

But all it does, is that the loader div disappears, then the main div appears like it should for a split second, then just dissappears. Thanks in advance for any help. #:)

Comment: since you are using jquery, use $(document).ready insteand that body onload. See if it works better.

Comment: Don't use onload. Also do not use inline events with jQuery. No point and they don't have all the features. Use a DOM ready event to control this.

Comment: Using $( document ).ready(function() { still does the same thing... See where you're coming from. Anything else? :/

Comment: you do not have a #main element but a .main element

Comment: @Blauharley Just was typing that... You need class selector not the ID selector. `$('.main')` and `$('.loader')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean for the loader to fade out after main has faded in, in which case you'll need to take advantage of the callback argument.

You can also use [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) rather than setting a timeout.

You should also use `$(document).ready()` rather than invoking the function in the `onload=""` handler.

```
$(function(){
  $('.main').delay(1000).fadeIn('fast', function(){
    $('.loader').fadeOut('fast');
  });
});
```

Noted by [Blauharley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253488/javascript-fadein-not-working-properly#comment52387390_32253488): You are targeting elements with an *ID* of main (and loader), whereas the elements in your markup use *classes*.

Comment: Classes, not ID selectors!

Comment: Thanks for the help, gave it a go and it still gave me the issue. Have a look for yourself here: http://starlight-radio.tk

Comment: No problem. That was the most likely cause of the original bug, but your example is much cleaner now.

Comment: Okay. Is this an issue in my code, or something else? I'm really confused by this as I've tried everything you guys have said.

Comment: @Sammyjo20 Have you fixed the selector as appropriate? (period for classes, hash sign for IDs)

Comment: @Sammyjo20: If the selector change does not fix it, show all your code and HTML, there may be another issue we do not see here.

Comment: Yes I have. Have you seen the site?

Comment: Okay. should I post it just here?

Comment: @Sammyjo20 Are you able to provide a live demo reproducing the issue? (Perhaps using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net))

Comment: Oh. My. God. I missed a ">" after the image. Look: <div class="loader" id="loader"><img src="images/loading.gif"</div>
<div class="main" id="main">